# Insert values into MongoDB (Node.js, mongojs, express)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

Respected ppl ...

Im trying to insert my jsons which im building into mongodb ...

```
     var newjson = JSON.stringify(json);

     console.log(newjson);

     db.mongostuds.save(newjson, function(err, saved) {
         if( err || !saved ) console.log("Record not saved");
         else console.log("Record saved");
     });
```

my connection is as follows :

```
var databaseUrl = "vtu";
var collections = ["mongostuds"]
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);
```

The db gets created but the data does not get inserted ....

I even tried removing my json and doing simple stuff like :

```
db.mongostuds.save({username : "admin"}, function(err, saved) {
    if( err || !saved ) { console.log("Record not saved"); }
    else { console.log("Record saved"); }
});
```

But still the record is not inserted ....

And ya i get "Record saved" in console log ...

This is the entire code :
https://github.com/SkyKOG/luckyvturesults.com/blob/master/app.js

Kindly do help ...

Thanks

Comment: saved is not null when you get Record Saved, console.log it! I use native mongo as my library and I had NO problems with it. I don't even have to stringify my json, I just put it in there.

Comment: Okay ill look into it ... 
But its not working for direct input too ... eg when i use {username : "admin"} ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code block works fine for me:

```
var databaseUrl = "vtu";
var collections = ["mongostuds"]
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections); 


db.mongostuds.save({username : "admin"}, function(err, saved) {
    if( err || !saved ) { console.log("Record not saved"); }
    else { console.log("Record saved"); }
});
```

Try running that without all the YQL and Express and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give DatabaseUrl in below form if your mongo server is not running on default host and port:

"username:password@host:port/dbName".

Comment: Hmmm ...this was not specified in the docs ... i did this but still the same ? ... and the db gets created fine ...inserting dosent happen ... 
And ya ...everything is running on default host and port ,,,,

Comment: As Old Pro suggested, i have too tried that code block, its working fine in my machine. Have u tried it?

Comment: Yes it worked ...i removed my stringify function :) ...

Comment: Yupp.. It was causing the problem, save function needs first argument as JSON and you were passing string. :)